# I am not able to execute aggregate operation on mongoDB using Groovy

Tags: mongodb, groovy, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am using **groovy language** to performs aggregation operations on mongoDB. Pipeline operation match, lookup, and project look like working fine. But I am getting the error in aggregate. I tried so many solutions regarding this error but none of them are not working for me. Can anyone help me?

```
c_1.insert(new BasicDBObject(["id" : 10, "name" : "abc", "lastName" : "kumar",  "companyId": 10]))    
c_2.insert(new BasicDBObject(["id" : 10, "companyName" : "Microsoft", "numEmployee" : 100 ]))  

// Build the $match operations
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("\$match", new BasicDBObject("id", 10));  

// Build the $lookup operations 
DBObject lookupFields = new BasicDBObject("from", "c_2");
lookupFields.put("localField", "companyId");
lookupFields.put("foreignField", "id");
lookupFields.put("as", "companydoc"); 
DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject("\$lookup", lookupFields);  

// Build the $project operations 
DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("name", 1);
projectFields.put("lastName", 1);
projectFields.put("companyId", 1);
projectFields.put("companyName", "\$c_2.companyName");       
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("\$project", projectFields); 
List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, lookup, project);  
AggregationOutput output = c_1.aggregate(pipeline.get(0), pipeline.get(1), pipeline.get(2))
```

**Error:** Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "/xx.xx.xx.xx:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument" , "code" : 9 , "codeName" : "FailedToParse"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved.

Used the latest version of mongo-java-driver.